# Translating taxonomy list name for a custom link in rewrite result field

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n, uri

Very hard to describe this problem in a title. Let me explain:

I have a taxonomy list named 'Meubelen'. I translated the name to 'Meubles' for the French version of the website.

I created a view of the terms in this list (an overview of categories). An image of a representative node is shown for each term. I like te rewrite the output of this image to a link directing to the taxonomy page. I can do this for one language, like this:

```
 meubelen/[term-name]
```

But this should change to

```
 meubles/[term-name]
```

when visiting the French side of the website.

How can I achieve this? There's no translatable field for this view that I can add and use as variable.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve this? There's no translatable field for this view that I can add and use as variable.

Really?!? If you have a representative node of the category content (with the proper language set) you should be able to have a relationship to that nodes language settings, and also the url path to nodes' url path for say, French, in this case.

There's no token support to Rewrite the link in Views to the path with X language setting for the node? .... eg, under `Replacement Tokens` for the field there's no configurable token for like, `node:path:lang:YOUR-LANG` or something similar -- I typically dont do internation sites, but i'm 99% sure this type of flexability comes out of the box.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I'm not trying to find the i18n-name for the node, but for the taxonomy list name.. I use the name of the list in Pathauto, like so: 

http://www.example.com/nl/**meubelen**/tafel
http://www.example.com/fr/**meubles**/table

I'd like to link the image of a representative node to the terms page. But in Views, I can't find the right translatable field for the bold part to use in rewrite field.